# HTML/CSS/JS Drawing a line from Point A to B

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically, I want to draw a line from point A (0vh|0vw) to point B (50vh|50vw).
I first thought of using a div with a border and a height of 1 PX that I rotated to get the effect.

The problem with that is that if the site size changes when the user is using an unusual monitor or when he resizes the window, the rotation angle is not right anymore.

So what I want is to draw a line from a fixed point A to a fixed point B, automatically changing the degree of rotation when the site is resized.

Comment: Have you looked into SVG?

Comment: No, thanks for the Tipp

Comment: Use an `hr` rather than a div but: yeah you can totally do this with CSS. Set the `width` to the length of your triangle's hypotenuse, and set to the rotation using fancypants modern CSS that uses `calc()` and friends to compute the angle. That said, SVG _would_ be a heck of a lot easier =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As manassehkatz stated, you could use an SVG.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="50vw" y2="50vh" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

You could also use a canvas, but it requires you to implement custom resizing and rendering.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('line-drawing').getContext('2d');

function update() {
  Object.assign(ctx.canvas, {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  });
}

function render() {
  const { width, height } = ctx.canvas;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(~~(width / 2), ~~(height / 2));
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.stroke();
}

update();
render();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  update();
  render();
});
```

```css
#line-drawing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="line-drawing"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok, this is what helped me to solve my problem, thank you very much.

Comment: hi @Dragomy could you expand on what you did in the end because I can't get the vw/vh units to work in that way.

Comment: @AHaworth
Yeah, sure, so this is what I did:
"""
<svg width="50vw" height="50vh" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
"""
This draws a line from P1 (0vw|0vh) to P2 (50vw|50vh), but the point is that instead of thinking like drawing from a point to a point, you draw from a point in a direction for an amount. Sorry I dont know how to scale code correctly in comments :/

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks, so the vw/vh go on the SVG itself, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an `hr` rather than a `div` (since it's basically just a rotated horizontal rule) but: yeah, you can totally do this with CSS. However, it needs some functions that at the time of this answer only work in Safari, and Firefox: the CSS [sqrt()](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_sqrt) and [atan2](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_atan2) functions.

We can set the width of our `hr` to your triangle's hypotenuse, and set the rotation using `atan2` (for more info on this rather special function, see its [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). It's so important, it's literally baked into CPUs as a lowest-level machine instruction) to compute an angle given a distance and rise:

```css
main {
  --w: 200;
  --h: 100;
  width: calc(1px * var(--w));
  height: calc(1px * var(--h));
  background: red;
}

.line {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  transform-origin: 0 0;

  /* line from (0,0) to (50% width, 50% height): */
  --lw: calc(var(--w) / 2);
  --lh: calc(var(--h) / 2);

  /* calculate our hypotenuse length and angle: */
  --m: calc(pow(var(--lw), 2) + pow(var(--lh), 2));
  --hyp: sqrt(var(--m));
  width: calc(1px * var(--hyp));

  --angle: atan2(var(--lh), var(--lw));
  transform: rotate(var(--angle));
}
```

```html
<main>
  <hr class="line"/>
</main>
```

Of course, using SVG would be a heck of a lot easier, and would have better compatibility =D

Answer (score 0):

A simple (simplistic) way of doing this in CSS is to clip a div which is covering the whole viewport.

Here's an example:

```html
<style>
  .line {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 2px 0, calc(50% + 2px) 50%, 50% 50%);
    position: fixed;
  }
</style>
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use 100vh,100vw to body and inside use only px,so the screen will be adapitate but the size of stick no